# Makita product lines comparison

Tags: hand-tools

I have been looking at different Makita tools and I can see what seems to be two different product lines but I fail to find any information online that would suggest what is the actual differences between the models. For example there are **XMT** and **DTM** models of multitools and all I can see is that both have variable speed control dial (6, 000 to 20, 000 OPM) and that's it. The price ranges differ quite a lot while the DTMs are significantly cheaper. Can anyone shed some light and point to any actual differences between those model lines?

Comment: Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic here. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: After using my first Makita drill , I replaced all my power tools with Makita brand tools ( except the radial arm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Makita XMT series of tools is marketed toward tradespeople and professionals while the DMT is for the mass market.  Little outward differences but generally there are significant differences in durability and reliability.  You'll find DMT at big box stores and the like.  Usually you'll only find XMT at professional supply outlets.

If you are just going to be using it for typical homeowner duties, the DMT is your best value.  If you expect to use the tool to make a living, then consider XMT.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much for the info! I am just curious how such a significant fact is so hard to find using the official Makita sources.